# How can i include a space (' ') in the resulting concatenated string?

Tags: string, loops, user-defined-functions, string-concatenation, string.h

The question assigned to me says that when the output of the concatenated string is given, it must have a space ' ' between the 1st and the 2nd string, also, use of in-built function "strcat()" is prohibited. For Example String1=Hello, String2=World, ConcatenatedString=Hello(space)World. I need an assistance. Thank you.

```
void strconcat(char s1[15], char s2[15])
{  
int i; 
printf("ENTER A STRING : ");
gets(s1);
printf("ENTER A STRING : ");
gets(s2);

while (s1[i] != '\0')
{   
    i++;

}
    for (int j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++, i++)
{                                                
    s1[i] = s2[j];      
}

s1[i] = '\0';
puts(s1);

}
```

Comment: You have 1 error. You need to initialize `i = 0` first.

Comment: Is `sprintf()` prohibited too? BTW, it's funny that `strcat()` is prohibited but not `gets()` which is prohibited by every (good) manual and ended up being removed from the C standard... Doesn't your compiler tell you not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the in-built c function, [`size_t strlen(const char *str)`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) then you can save the first while loop.

```
void strconcat(char s1[15], char s2[15])
{
int i = 0; // You have not initialized this in your code.
printf("ENTER A STRING : ");
gets(s1);
printf("ENTER A STRING : ");
gets(s2);

i = strlen(s1); // If the use of in-built strlen is not allowed then just use the below two lines
s1[i] = ' '; // Here i is at the position of '\0' character in s1 array.
i++;
for (int j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++, i++)
{                                                
    s1[i] = s2[j];      
}

s1[i] = '\0';
puts(s1);
}
```